# Manjaro install ncurses5-compat-libs

Tags: archlinux, manjaro, pacman-package-manager

I'm trying to install this package `ncurses5-compat-libs` but I can because of the following problem.

***What I did:***

**1. yay ncurses5-compat-libs**

There are 2 types of errors: 
Either I will check 'Y' and I will add the key, so in this case, I will receive the error message as follow

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Permission denied
==> Error: Problem importing keys
```

Or I will check as 'n' to don't add the key and I will receive

```
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
    ncurses-6.1.tar.gz ... FAILED (unknown public key 702353E0F7E48EDB)
==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
Error downloading sources: ncurses5-compat-libs
```

**2. sudo gpg --recv-keys C52048C0C0748FEE227D47A2702353E0F7E48EDB**

I've tried to add it manually but it didn't work.

**3. sudo gpg --recv-keys 702353E0F7E48EDB**

Also this one I've tried to add it manually but it didn't work

**4. yay -S --noconfirm --needed ncurses5-compat-libs**

**5. Trying to fallow this [forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204240)**

and least but not last

**6. I've tried to clone the repository by hand by following**

```
git clone http://aur.archlinux.org/ncurses5-compat-libs.git 
cd ncurses5-compat-libs
sudo gpg --recv-keys C52048C0C0748FEE227D47A2702353E0F7E48EDB
makepkg -sic
cd ..
sudo rm -r ncurses5-compat-libs
```

And guess what, I'm back from where I started...

```
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
    ncurses-6.1.tar.gz ... FAILED (unknown public key 702353E0F7E48EDB)
==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
Error downloading sources: ncurses5-compat-libs
```

Dose any of you guys have any idea how can I fix this problem? If so let me know because I'm getting crazy already not been able to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need specifically `ncurses5-compat-libs` if you have a higher version of ncurses. Because version 6 is backwards compatible with version 5. You need to check whether you have `libtinfo.so.6` or not. If you **have** it then you just need to create a system link. Check if you have `libtinfo.so.6`, so **Run:**

```
ls /lib/ | grep libtinfo
```

if you **can't see** `libtinfo.so.6`, you need to install ncurses (the current latest version of it: 6.2) and then create a system link that I mentioned below. so run:

```
sudo pacman -S ncurses
sudo pacman -S lib32-ncurses
```

if you **have** `libtinfo.so.6` then run:

```
sudo link /lib/libtinfo.so.6 /lib/libtinfo.so.5
```

Comment: For me `sudo link /lib/libncursesw.so.6.2 /lib/libncurses.so.5` fixed the issues. Using v6 and relying on v5-backwards-compatibility seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I went a step further from creating the link in the other answer here:

```
sudo link /lib/libtinfo.so.6 /lib/libtinfo.so.5
```

And created a dummy package so I could build something that depended on that being a thing:

```
$ cat /opt/aur/ncurses5-compat-libs-dummy/PKGBUILD
pkgname='ncurses5-compat-libs'
pkgver=6.1
pkgrel=1
arch=(any)
provides=('libtinfo5')

$ cd /opt/aur/ncurses5-compat-libs/dummy
$ makepkg -si
```

worked like a charm